# Need help in creating splash intro page using custom page template

Tags: page-template

I'm trying to create splash/intro page using custom page template in wordpress theme. I tried following the tutplus.com guide and it works perfectly. But I wanted somewhat modern web design and put a step ahead and used third party website design tools and created sample page and now I'm trying to add this as custom page template but can't make it work. Styles are missing and only text appears.

I'm attaching the custom page files which I've created using design tool and the image of the folder structure comparing with my wordpress theme contents.

[image: Folder Structure]

I'm not pro so please explain me in detail so that I can do it on my own.

With reply to @dingo_d the Code used in function.php

```
<?php
if (is_page_template('pageintro.php')) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'splash_intro_scripts');
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'splash_intro_scripts' ) ){
    function splash_intro_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerymin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/jquery-2.1.0.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'blocs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/blocs.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheet/bootstrap.css', array( ),'');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheet/font-awesome.min.css', array( ),'');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesplash_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheet/style-splash.css', array( ),'');

    }
}
```

---

---

Dingo,thank you for helping me.The steps and the code were really helpful for me. But still its not perfect and some thing is missing. I had to move the splash-style.css and img folder to the root to make it work. Though very near to the perfection now I think some scripts are not loading or theme problem. Here is the web page screenshot how it looks after the new changes.

[image]

Comment: This is the tutplus.com guide [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-a-splash-page-with-wordpress--wp-22971).

Comment: Why don't you just put those styles in your style.css??

Comment: @dingo_d I tried that way but didn't work. Do I've to do anything after edit, like clearing cache etc.?

Comment: You'd need to enque `bootstrap` and `blocks.js` on splash page, as well as font awesome. Basically you'd need to wrap those enqueue functions in  [is_page_template()](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) check (with `if()` statement). So when you're on that page those styles and scripts will be loaded. You can also enqueue your own style that way, for that template specifically.

Comment: @dingo_d You mean to say like said in this guide [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321). Right?

Comment: @dingo_d I tried that too but not sure what exactly I'm missing. Thats why I'm seeking help from someone who could actually try with my files and help me.

Comment: You should probably do this the right way from the beginning on. Read [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) on the WordPress Codex to get insights how page templates do work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go from the beginning.

First I'll walk you through the enqueing of styles and scripts. In your `functions.php` file add:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'splash_intro_scripts');

if ( ! function_exists( 'splash_intro_scripts' ) ){
    function splash_intro_scripts() {
        if (is_page_template('page-intro.php')) {
            wp_enqueue_style('google_font_1', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&subset=latin,latin-ext');
            wp_enqueue_style('google_font_2', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext');
            wp_enqueue_style('google_font_3', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab&subset=latin,latin-ext');

            wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', false );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'blocs',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/blocs.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', false );

            wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array( ),'');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array( ),'');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesplash_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style-splash.css', array( ),'');
        }
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, find where your `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',...);` is located in the `functions.php` file, and add the `if` statement there.

Now, the font is loaded via google, so you just put the necessary fonts with the url in the `wp_enqueue_style`.

You'll notice that my directories are a bit different than yours. You have `/javascript/` I have `/js/`; you have `/stylesheet/` I have `/css/`. Just change that to fit your theme (file structure). Then place all the necessary files except the `jquery`, because that is loaded by wordpress and there is no need to enqueue your own. That's why I've added the dependency of `bootstrap` to  `array('jquery')`.

You'll also need to put your fontawesome fonts folder inside the theme root folder.

Also the `/img` folder has to go to `/stylesheet` folder because your `style-splash.css` is inside `/stylesheet` folder (so it's looking the images from that folder on).

`blocks.js` needs to be modified in order to work.

You need to wrap everything inside in

```
jQuery(function($){ });
```

So:

```
jQuery(function($){

    // Loading page complete
    $(window).load(function()
    {
        checkHero(); // Check hero height is correct
        animateWhenVisible();  // Activate animation when visible
    });

 ... all the way down ...

    $(document).on('click', '.next-lightbox, .prev-lightbox', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var idx = $('a[data-lightbox]').index(targetLightbox);
            var next = $('a[data-lightbox]').eq(idx+1) // Next

            if($(this).hasClass('prev-lightbox'))
            {
                next = $('a[data-lightbox]').eq(idx-1) // Prev
            }
            $('#lightbox-image').attr('src',next.attr('data-lightbox'));
            $('.lightbox-caption').html(next.attr('data-caption'));
            targetLightbox = next;

            // Handle navigation buttons (next - prev)
            $('.next-lightbox, .prev-lightbox').hide();

            if($('a[data-lightbox]').index(next) != $('a[data-lightbox]').length-1)
            {
                $('.next-lightbox').show();
            }
            if($('a[data-lightbox]').index(next) > 0)
            {
                $('.prev-lightbox').show();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Otherwise you'll have errors. And the `page-intro.php`

template file is just:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Splash Intro
*/

get_header();

?>

<div class="page-container">

<!-- Hero Bloc -->
<div id="hero-bloc" class="bloc hero bgc-white bg-walkway d-bloc">
    <div class="container bloc-sm hero-nav">
        <nav class="navbar row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Company</a>
                <button id="nav-toggle" type="button" class="ui-navbar-toggle navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-1">
                <ul class="site-navigation nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a id="pl-undefined" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="v-center">
        <div class="vc-content row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/106743683" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1 class=" mg-lg text-center">
                    It's all about the big hero strapline.
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div><a id="scroll-hero" class="btn-dwn" href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Hero Bloc END -->

<!-- Bloc Group -->
<div class='bloc-group'>

<!-- bloc-2 -->
<div class="bloc bgc-white bloc-tile-2 bg-citysky d-bloc" id="bloc-2">
    <div class="container bloc-lg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3 class="mg-md text-justify ">
                    <strong>BENEFITS</strong>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-justify ">
                    Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- bloc-2 END -->

<!-- bloc-3 -->
<div class="bloc bgc-white bloc-tile-2 bg-citysky d-bloc" id="bloc-3">
    <div class="container bloc-lg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3 class="mg-md ">
                    <strong>COLLABORATION</strong>
                </h3>
                <p class=" text-justify">
                    Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio dui. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- bloc-3 END -->
</div>
<!-- Bloc Group END -->

<!-- Footer - bloc-4 -->
<div class="bloc bgc-white bg-walkway d-bloc" id="bloc-4">
    <div class="container bloc-lg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                    <a class="social-lg" href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-twitter icon-lg"></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                    <a class="social-lg" href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook icon-lg"></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                    <a class="social-lg" href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-dribbble icon-lg"></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                    <a class="social-lg" href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-instagram icon-lg"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer - bloc-4 END -->
</div>
<!-- Main container END -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Basically all your html just pasted inside. And that's it.

If you don't want your header or footer to show you'll have to modify it a bit. Either by changing the `header.php` and `footer.php` or by hiding them with css.

That's it. I've placed everything like I described in my test twentysixteen theme, and it works.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, one more question. I have to add the code to functions.php file. Right?

Comment: Yes, put it in functions.php

Comment: Sorry no luck. Still no styles only text.

Comment: Please check my edited question. You can find the code I've used as advised.

Comment: `is_page_template` won't work until after the query runs.

Comment: What query? It just checks if you're currently in the page template :\

Comment: `functions.php` loads before the main query executes, so `is_page_template` will always be false when that code runs.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tested the old code and it didn't execute, I've changed it so that it works now

Comment: @dingo_d Still no luck. I've tried your new code. Think I'm missing some thing.  So far what I've done is - First created a php page and copied all the style.css code to head tags and all the content in body tags. Next I navigated to editor from the themes section and opened functions.php and pasted your code at the bottom. Then tried opening the page which has been setup with my php page template. Now I guess css styles are applied but still irregularities in design, think scripts are not loading yet. Could you please try my files in wordpress setup and let me know whats going wrong.

Comment: I don't have access to your files. How could I test it? The above code works on default wordpress theme. As I've said, be sure to have `get_header()` of `get_footer()` in your splash page template...

Comment: @dingo_d Sorry I thought you'd have noticed the download link to my files in my question. Its still there under the image. Also I'll post the link here now. Please find the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c45wq1ogb1sqprz/AACjV3aJOfXKiY_GO3YtwOGya?dl=0) . Thank you.

Comment: I'll try it when I get home and post the answer here.

Comment: @dingo_d Thank you. Will be waiting for your reply. Also the files which I gave you are the ones which I've tried before posting this question so you see the old code there. Please edit the code and try it.

Comment: @i0s, I've added the answer. This works for me, so there shouldn't be any issues for you too. Hope it's ok. If it is, feel free to +1 me and accept the answer :)

Comment: Ok, so first of all, I do not approve getting themes off of ripped sites. It's not right by the theme authors (they actually make a living off them), and it's a big security risk! I don't know if the theme contains any malicious code or not (since it was not purchased but downloaded from unsecured site). Second, the theme has tons of bad and deprecated code. I got notices for sidebar id's not being set, and deprecated WP_Widget constructor. I seriously advise you to buy a theme and contact the author about any issues.

Comment: @dingo_d Sorry. You've got it right and wrong. I agree never pirate others hard work. I'm using licensed version 1.03 and updated version. The one I've linked is the version which I downloaded from third party sites and been told to buy full version to get premium features and updates. I can't share my licensed theme publicly due the terms and conditions. Just thought we are very near in fixing issue and sharing it will make things clear. Anyway I'll remove the link now and thank you for your timely help. Much appreciated.